# displaying weights & activations in cnn & unet

Tags: python, tensorflow, pytorch, conv-neural-network

I am programming in Python using Tensorflow, Numpy and Matplotlib and wanted to see how to visualize weights learnt and also activations in a diagram of my CNN.

The basic flow of my algorithm (which I would like represented in my diagram) is as follows:

1. Input image
2. Binarize the image
3. Run image through CNN (basic `conv2d` with `relu`/`maxpool`)
4. Run it through many examples of input data.

I would like to visualize the weights learnt.

I would also like to have an unlabelled image that I want to test against and also visualize the weights for while testing.

Is there a way to visualize using images instead of trying to use TensorBoard?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, here is a nice library for you to use for this purpose: [Keract](https://github.com/philipperemy/keract).

Use the function `get_activations` then `display_activations`.

Comment: thanks a lot! I still get the following error: NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-8043d3de8409> in <module>()
----> 1 keract.get_activations(model, x, layer_name=None, nodes_to_evaluate=None, output_format='simple', auto_compile=True)

NameError: name 'keract' is not defined

Comment: is this import working `from keract import get_activations
`

Comment: yes the import is working but after that i get the error.. not sure why. thanks